# Authorize.net, Paypal or Google Checkout, which one should I go with?

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, payment-gateway, google-checkout, authorize.net

Which payment gateway should I choose from among Authorize.net, PayPal & Google Checkout?

Is there anything wrong if I provide all ? I'm planning for express checkout methods in all the three services, the direct credit card accepting service.

Comment: How is this related to programming, pray tell?

Comment: This is basically a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67394/which-should-i-implement-first-paypal-or-google-checkout-on-my-ecommerce-websit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paypal is of course the most well known and respected, however the answer actually depends on the amount of revenue your company will make (monthly and yearly averages), the average price per transaction and the number of debit card vs credit card payments you are likly to take.  Without these figures it's nigh on impssible to determine which one is cheapest for you.

Comment: Respected, is an opinion, and it's popular in the US, but not necessarily everywhere else.

Comment: Paypal is certainly not respected.

Answer (score 2):

The more choices you offer, the more choices your customers have, so no, there is nothing wrong with offering all three.

If you potentially have customers from the EU or Asia, you may want to investigate options that are popular in those regions as well.

Comment: Thanks! thats all I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind, PayPal tends to freeze money in account for some reason and have huge problems even answering email with 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Authorize.Net is only a payment gateway, not a payment processor. You need to have a US based merchant account to use with Authorize.Net.

Paypal and Google Checkout are third party payment processors. They essentially are the payment gateway and merchant account rolled into one package.

Answer (score -3):

It's worth noting, from the research I've done, using PayPal is cheaper than credit card processing directly. They charge less of a fee (I'm assuming because they process everything themselves, and don't go through some third party to get to the credit card company).